# NetBean/Eclipse to develop Jboss ESB

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss-esb

Can someone suggest me which IDE(NetBean/Eclipse) is best to develop JBoss ESB project?

Comment: I would Prefer to use the JBOSS Dev Studio - An Eclipse based studio.

Answer (score 0):

Install the SOA Functionality on Top of NetBeans IDE 6.7